# emulating DB view in spring-boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

My entity is mapped to a DB table.

I need to re-map it to another table with a where condition. The easiest way would be to create a DB view.

```
create view person_main_asg as (
select * from person_history 
where asg_end_date is null or asg_end_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

The problem is that I don't have permissions to create it.

So I need to solve the problem in my spring-boot application.

Googling around I found that I can add a filter to my entity definition.

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name="person_history_main_asg")
@Filter(name="person_history_main_asg", condition = "asg_end_date is null or asg_end_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ")
@Table(name = "person_history")
public class Person {
///...
}
```

Now I need to enable my filter because it's disabled by default.

It turned out to be a difficult task.

One [solution](http://cyriltech.blogspot.ch/2017/03/how-to-enable-hibernate-filter-using.html) is to use AOP/AspectJ. It seems to me more a hack than an answer but the main problem is that it requires to modify VM arguments by adding `javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` which I'm not allowed to do.

Another solution is to implement a repository which is currently defined as an interface

```
public interface PersonRepository  {

    Person findByFullLoginEndingWith(String login);

    List<Person> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName);
    List<Person> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String lastName);
}
```

So the implementation is supposed to be

```
public interface PersonRepositoryCustom  {
    Person findByFullLoginEndingWith(String login);

    List<Person> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName);
    List<Person> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String lastName);
}

public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person>, PersonRepositoryCustom {
}

public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person findOne(Specification<Person> spec) {
        Filter filter = (Filter)entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("person_history_main_asg");
        Person result = personRepository.findOne(spec);
        return result;
    }

    public Person findOne(String id) {
       //...
    }

    public List<Person> findAll() {
       //...
    }

    public List<Person> findAll(Specification<Person> spec) {
       //...
    }

    //...
}
```

I have several problems with this solution (in addition that it is bulk and heavy).

EntityManager causes the following error: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4

Also

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;
```

causes stackoverflow because it's an instance of `PersonRepositoryImpl`  which is autowired but I need to access the default implementation by Springboot.

So how I can emulate a DB view in my application?

EDIT:

Currently my entity is mapped to another table. 
And my entity repository is defined as

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {

        T findOne(ID id);
        List<T> findAll();

        Person findByFullLoginEndingWith(String login);

        List<Person> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName);
        List<Person> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String lastName);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a view for that? Just write a `find` method in your repository put `@Query(value="select * from person_history 
where asg_end_date is null or asg_end_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nativeQuery=true)` on it and be done. Why make it more complex then that.

Comment: @M. Deinum If I implement my repository PersonRepositoryImpl then I need to provide implementation of findAll(Specification<Person> spec). So I need to extract conditions from spec and combine them with my Query. I don't know how to do it. Or could you please give a draft solution as an answer.

Comment: You don't need an implementation. As asked why do you need that view ? There is no need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an implementation, you don't need filters, you don't need a view. Just define a query method and annotate it with `@Query`.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository {

    Person findByFullLoginEndingWith(String login);

    List<Person> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName);
    List<Person> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String lastName);

    @Query(value="select * from person_history where asg_end_date is null or asg_end_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Person> findPersonMain();
}
```

That is all you need, no custom implementation etc. as Spring Data JPA will  know what to do with that. Currently it is a native query but you can probably rewrite it to a JPQL one.

=====================================================================

EDITED BY Oleg Pavliv:

The solution is to use @Where instead of @Filter (taken from the thread of comments).

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "asg_end_date is null or asg_end_date > GETDATE()) ")
@Table(name = "person_history")
public class Person {
///...
}
```

Comment: Please check my edit to OP. My repository extends ReadOnlyRepository and JpaSpecificationExecutor. If I just add a method findPersonMain as you suggested it won't be taken into account.

Comment: I still don't get why you need the view, or what the fact that your person is mapped to a different table has to do with this. As I mentioned you don't need the view. Why would you need it?

Comment: My entity is mapped to a Person table. I need to re-map it to another table using additional where conditions to have the same results. The easiest way would be to create a view. Your implementation does not work because it's not compatible with my current repository definition which extends ReadOnlyRepository and JpaSpecificationExecutor. If I just add a method as you suggested it won't be taken into account and the result select statements won't include the Query condition.

Comment: And why wouldn't it work? What is `ReadOnlyRepository`? It looks like you are using Spring Data JPA, so why wouldn't it work? You can only map it to a table (or view) if that actually exists if it doesn't you cannot map it. I still don't see why on earth you would need a view for this whilst a simple query can do the same.

Comment: ReadOnlyRepository is an interface extending Repository. I removed it from OP. I don't know why it doesn't work. My question is how to attach a where condition to every query which is generated automatically by Spring Data.

Comment: That is a completely different question. Use a filter for that (and no you don't need to attach a java agent it works with basic Spring AOP as well). Or specify a `@Where` on your entity which will include this for every person query (literally every query).